# Simple inequality of composition of linear maps over normed vector spaces

Tags: analysis, inequality, linear-transformations, normed-spaces

Let $(V,||•||_V), (W,||•||_W), (X,||•||_X)$ be normed vector spaces and let $T:V\to W$ and $S:W\to X$ both be continuous with respect to their associated norms.

a) Show that $S(T(v)) : V\to X$ is continuous.
b) Show that: $$ ||S•T||\leq||S||||T||$$

I think I have done the first by simply adjusting the inequalities for the continuity of the original two maps but I am interested if there is another way. But I have clue how the second part works, I am trying to use the boundedness of the maps but I don’t know if this is the correct method. Any help is appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We have $T(v)=w$, $S(T(v))=S(w)=x$, now $\|S(T(v))\|=\|S(w)\| \le \|S\| \|w\|=\|S\| \|T(v)\| \le \|S\| \|T\| \|v\| $, where all the norms are taken in the respectives spaces. So we have:

$$\|S(T(v))\| \le \|S\| \|T\| \|v\|, \; \forall v \in V. $$
Now since the norm of the operator is the least value (the inf) such that the inequality always holds we have:

$$\| S \bullet T\|\le \|S \| \|T \|.$$
This also show point a).